# How can i select array elements what name contains numbers?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, select

At first, im beginner.

I want to push elements from array to another array what does not contain numbers

I have an array1:

```
0 => string '142221A' (length=7)
  1 => string 'hOUSES' (length=6)
  2 => string 'bOOKS' (length=5)
  3 => string 'sHOES' (length=5)
  4 => string '92921' (length=5)
  5 => string '12231' (length=5)
  6 => string 'cARS' (length=4)
  7 => string 'tOYS' (length=4)
```

The output i want like this, array2:

```
  0 => string 'hOUSES' (length=6)
  1 => string 'bOOKS' (length=5)
  2 => string 'sHOES' (length=5) 
  3 => string 'cARS' (length=4)
  4 => string 'tOYS' (length=4)
```

I dont want a solution, i want the way for it.

Comment: Use `array_filter()` with a callback function that checks if the value contains numbers.

Answer (score 1):

in PHP you can use `is_numeric()` method to check the string is a just a numeric or not as the following way:

```
$elements = ['142221A','hOUSES','bOOKS','sHOES','92921','12231','cARS','tOYS'];
$string_array = [];
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if(!is_numeric($element)) {
        array_push($string_array, $element);
    }
}
print_r($string_array);
```

but if you want to filter elements of an array to just have the elements that don't have any numeric value inside of it use the following way:

```
$elements = ['142221A','hOUSES','bOOKS','sHOES','92921','12231','cARS','tOYS'];

$just_string = [];

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    //it will check for the element which has a digit number inside of it or not
   //if it doesn't contain any number then it will be added to new array
    if(preg_match('~[0-9]~', $element) != 1){
        array_push($just_string, $element);
    }
}

print_r($just_string);
```

Comment: thanks! but with this method the first one '142221A' goes to new array. There are numbers and one character. This is my real problem.

Comment: Because the first element is not a number and a combination of number with string

Comment: I edited the code and added a second solution to the question to just filter strings without any number characeter.

Comment: perfect, thank you!